# Proving what the isometry group of a "chess board" is

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, plane-geometry, symmetry, isometry

"Find the group of symmetries of a chess board", was the original question. As stated is not very rigorous, i intrepreted it as asking to find a (setwise) stabilizer of the group of $\mathbb{R}^2$ isometries acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the expected way. That is, the stabilizer of the set (or a set equivalent in some sense to) $$C :=\{[n, n+1]\times [m, m+1] :(1,1)\leq (n,m)\leq (8,8) \ \ \mathrm{and} \ \ n+m = 1 \ \ \mathrm{(mod\ \ 2)}\}.$$

This is not very pleasant to work with. We can go with cases: it's easy to show that translations don't fix $C$. Due to corners, rotations must at worst be the same of a square; there might be a slick way to show the only plausible reflexions are the same as of a square.

Then by cases we could show non $\pi$ rotation can't work, looking at corners again, thankfully rotation matrix is simple in this case so it's not too hard...  We can also show 2 reflexions don't work looking at corners;

It remains to show whether the $\pi$-rotation $r$ work, $rf$ (reflexion followed by 90 degree rotation) and $r^3f$ works (reflexion followed by 270 degree rotation). We can save work since showing 2 of them work implies the other does too. But this is still really tedious..

What are better ways to approach this (kind of) problem, without sacrificing rigor?

Comment: I wouldn't try and write down a formula for the chess board as a set, I would just argue that corners must go to corners, moreover white corners and black corners should go to white and black corners respectively.  That gives only 4 possible symmetries since fixing the corners fixes the chess board.  Then you can see pretty clearly that all 4 possibilities are valid and deduce what the group is.

Comment: @Jim Intuitively it seems to make sense, however this is not rigorous. Intuition often is wrong, so i cannot accept this as a proof.

Comment: Just because you don't write down a formula doesn't mean it's not rigorous.  The argument I outlined doesn't rely on intuition.

Comment: @Jim The first part seems clear to me, but i can't "see pretty clearly that all 4 possibilities are valid".

Comment: Do you own a chess board?  You could do this with an actual chess board if you're having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: As a formalist, i don't consider using an actual chess board a valid proof.

Comment: The question was posed about an actual chess board.  Also, there's nothing about formalism that requires you to forgo visual aids for developing your argument.

Comment: I'm not against using visual aids to develop an argument, as long as they're just aids and not themselves part of the proof. I will edit the question to reflect on that.